# A strange "fatal: Could not read from remote repository." with crontab

Tags: git, cron

I use `git init --bare example.git` create git repo in my localhost, user is git.

and I use root to git clone, run every minute with crontab, the command is:

```
*/1 * * * * git --git-dir=/opt/xxx/.git --work-tree=/opt/xxx pull 1>>/tmp/git.log 2>&1
```

the output log is:

> Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

Then I try:

```
 */1 * * * * cd /opt/xxx/ && git pull 1>>/tmp/git2.log 2>&1
```

But the output is the same.

If I run in command line, all is ok:

> Already up-to-date.

I don't know why can't run with crontab?

Comment: You may need to specify the paths in which you are working. Also `*/1` is same as `*`.

Comment: @fedorqui, which path? I specify the path by `--work-tree`

Comment: Ah right, I see. Try using the full path of `git` binary, normally `/usr/bin/git` (you can get it with `which git`).

Comment: Cron obviously finds Git, so that's not the problem. $HOME should be set to the user's home directory, but that's something to doublecheck. I'd also try SSHing to the remote, passing `-vv` to SSH to get additional diagnostic output, including which keys are tried.

Comment: Please do not use the root use for this. Adjust the permissions for /opt/xxx instead so that a regular user can do the pull.

Comment: @MagnusBäck I use `git-shell` as user git's login-shell, and my private ssh-key has password, I have use ssh-agent to load it and only  this one. The other, about the permission, my crontab run by root.

Comment: @MagnusBäck I have change owner of /opt/xxx and still output the same log

Comment: Agent-based authentication requires that the SSH process has access to the $SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable, but that variable won't be set when run via the crontab.

Comment: @MagnusBäck right! thank you very much! Can you put you reply as answer and I can choose yours as right answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agent-based authentication requires that the SSH process has access to the $SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable, but that variable won't be set when run via the crontab. You may want to  consider switching to a passphrase-less keypair or an anonymous authentication method.

If that's not an option you could write the contents of the $SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable (possibly also $SSH_AGENT_PID) to a local file that you can read from your crontab-run script and set the variables so that they're available to SSH.

One last option is to drop the crontab entry and manually start up a shell script that runs as a daemon and periodically performs the pull.

Comment: Your suggestion to use an anonymous authentication method worked great for me. I just did the initial `git clone` from the public github repo using the `https` URL format, and then subsequent `pull`s didn't need authentication.